# Use awk to display devices with disk usage above 10%, and print the column headings as well

Tags: linux, awk, disk-access

The below command displays devices with file system usage above 10%. However it is  not displaying the column headings. This is the command I use:

```
df -Ph | awk '+$5 >= 10 {print}'
```

---

I want output like this

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00   9.7G  1.9G  7.4G  21% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol     5.0G  665M  4.1G  14% /app 
server:/data                      5.0G  546M  4.3G  12% /data
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this using two conditions for awk to print the line: either disk usage is above 10%, either the first parameter is "Filesystem":

```
df -Ph | awk '(+$5 >= 10 || $1=="Filesystem") {print}'
```

**edit** as suggested by Jotne you can write this shorter like this (print is default action):

```
df -Ph | awk '+$5>=10 || $1=="Filesystem"'
```

Comment: You do not need the parentheses and no need the `print`, so it could be done like this: `df -Ph | awk '+$5>=10 || $1=="Filesystem"'`

Answer (score 3):

Print if we are looking at the first line or the fifth field is greater than or equal to 10.

```
df -Ph | awk 'NR==1 || +$5 >= 10'
```

Awk's default action is to print the line so block can be omitted.

Comment: +1 that is THE way to do this in awk. I've never seen just `+$5` used to force a numeric comparison, I've always used `($5+0)`. Do you know if that's guaranteed to work and portable?